# Why these printk's doesn't appear in dmesg?

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, virtualization, kvm, printk

I have provided few debug message in .S file and expected it to be appeared in dmesg output.

Following is the snippet:

```
--- a/arch/arm/kvm/interrupts.S
+++ b/arch/arm/kvm/interrupts.S
@@ -98,6 +98,8 @@ ENTRY(__kvm_vcpu_run)

    save_host_regs

+   printk(KERN_ALERT "Yes, into vcpu run : #\n"); 
+       
    restore_vgic_state
    restore_timer_state

 @@ -349,6 +351,8 @@ hyp_hvc:
     */
    push    {r0, r1, r2}

+   printk(KERN_ALERT "Yes, Guset traps happened : #\n"); 
+
    @ Check syndrome register
    mrc     p15, 4, r1, c5, c2, 0   @ HSR
    lsr     r0, r1, #HSR_EC_SHIFT
 @@ -395,6 +399,8 @@ THUMB(      orr     lr, #1)
 1:     eret

 guest_trap:
+  .ascii  "Yes, Guset traps happened : #\n"
+   printk(KERN_ALERT "Yes, Guset traps happened : #\n");  
    load_vcpu                       @ Load VCPU pointer to r0
    str     r1, [vcpu, #VCPU_HSR]
```

After launching a KVM guest, I was expecting PRINTK's should print in dmesg.But
it didn't appear?

Comment: Can you use a 'C' `printk()` call in assember?  Did you try to setup R0,R1 and use `bl printk`?

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I got your point.

Comment: @artlessnoise, I do see "/tmp/ccM8r29d.s: Error: unaligned opcodes detected in executable segment" error message while compilation

Comment: You need to put your `.ascii` strings outside the `.text` section or at least use `.align` after them?  Also make sure you jump around the strings; they won't appear in different sections unless you tell the assembler.